# SQLite replace every specified subpath with a new path

Tags: python, regex, sqlite, path, regexp-replace

Here is original output from track_locations table in sqlite3:

### Table track_locations

*attribute location*
*'/Users/marcosvelazquez/Documents/Music/loops/Manuel Tur - 123 BPM.mp3'*

*attribute directory*
*'/Users/marcosvelazquez/Documents/Music/loops'**

**I want a query that changes the**

*'/Users/marcosvelazquez/Documents'*

**path to**

*'/home/marc/Music'*

**So my new output would be:**

### Table track_locations

*attribute location*
*'/home/marc/Music/Music/loops/Manuel Tur - 123 BPM.mp3'*

*attribute directory*
*'/home/marc/Music/Music/loops'**

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('mixxxdb.sqlite')cur = con.cursor()

for row in cur.execute('''SELECT location, directory FROM track_locations'''):
    rowTuple = row
    newLocation = ''
    newDir = ''
    newTuple = ()

    # Modifies the path for both location and directory
    newLocation = rowTuple[0]
    newLocation = newLocation.split('/Users/marcosvelazquez/Documents') 
    newLocation = '/home/marc/Music' + newLocation[1]
    print(newLocation)

    newDir = rowTuple[1]
    newDir = newDir.split('/Users/marcosvelazquez/Documents')
    newDir = '/home/marc/Music' + newDir[1]
    print(newDir)

    cur.execute('''UPDATE track_locations SET location = newLocation''')
    cur.execute('''UPDATE track_locations SET directory = newDir''')
```

Did a couple searches but did not find the answer. So then I tried with sqlite. Here is the query I have:

```
UPDATE track_locationsSET location = '/home/marc/Music' | ltrim(location,'/Users/marcosvelazquez/Documents')

WHERE location IS NOT NULL;
```

This unfortunetly did not work either.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's better to include your problem in the body too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the SQLite function [replace()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#replace) is what you are looking for :

```
UPDATE track_locations
SET location = replace(location, '/Users/marcosvelazquez/Documents', '/home/marc/Music'),
directory = replace(directory, '/Users/marcosvelazquez/Documents', '/home/marc/Music')
```